# Is there a way to get the file menu on the top bar?

Tags: 18.04, menu

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I see there is a menu on top that supplies a way to quit the selected app, but this seems half implemented.

[image: Picture of menu]

I would imagine the main (file++) menu could be exposed there like in previous versions of Ubuntu. Thus the following should be exposed there:

[image: File menu]

Is there a way to make this happen?